# Assign values to Labels Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

am new to iOS Programming, I have a issue regarding assigning values to labels, Below is what i get from a service

```
(
{
    EmpName = Peter;
    Relation = SouthAfrica;
},
{
    EmpName = Smith;
    Relation = WestIndies;
},
{
    EmpName = Andrew;
    Relation = England;
},
{
    EmpName = John;
    Relation = Australia;
},
{
    EmpName = Rahul;
    Relation = India;
}
)
```

Above i have got 5 records, my problem is how to assign each EmpName to 5 labels, like peter to Label1, Smith to Label2, Andrew to Label3 and so on. Am getting only first empName, Below is the code what i have tried.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonArray=nil;
    NSLog(@"responseString is%@",responseString);
    jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    profileArray=[jsonArray mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[jsonArray count]);

    if ([jsonArray count]==0) {

        NSLog(@"responseString is%@",responseString);

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Validation" message:@"Error Connecting to server" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"EmpName"];

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at UITableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tags to your labels (like tag = 1 for label1, tag = 2 for label2 ..... tag = 5 in label5) then in your else part you can get all labels with their tag.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        lbl.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"EmpName"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of know in response from server there are only 5 employees, but in future these could be 100 or less or more. So you should use UITableView for this. I hope you have knowledge of UITableView.

Comment: thanks, but i need it in ViewController not the TableView.

Comment: UITableView is added in UIViewController. If employees count could any number, then i prefer UITableView, because if there are 200 employee and you creates 200 label with for loop, then these will take too much memory. But if you use UITableView even there are 1000 employees, it will take memory for only those UITableViewCells which are visible on screen at particular time.